# Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $S=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}\subseteq V$. Let $I=\{X\subseteq S:X\text{ is linearly independent}\}$ ...

Tags: matroids

I am learning matroids and I saw the following example:

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $S=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}\subseteq V$. Let $I=\{X\subseteq S:X\text{ is linearly independent}\}$. Then $(S,I)$ is the vector matroid.

The problems is that I don't understand why this is true. If we have the $3\times 4$-Matrix[image]

and $A=\{e_1,e_2\}$, $B=\{e_2,e_3,e_4\}$, then the only vector that we can add to $A$ is $e_4$, but $A\times\{e_4\}$ isn't independent. I am sure that there is a mistake in my argument, but I can't find it.

Comment: Unlike StackOverflow where monospaced blocks are often used, we typeset math on Math SE using $\mathrm\LaTeX$. See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how.

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Comment: By $e_j$ you mean the $j$-th column vector of your matrix right? If that’s the case, I think you meant to write $A \cup \{e_4\}$, not $\times$, for the union of the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here $B\setminus A = \{e_3,e_4\}$ so it is not the case that $e_4$ is the only vector that can be added to $A$. Clearly $A\cup\{e_3\}$ is independent.